# How to configure Mondrian embedded sample for XMLA communication

Tags: mdx, pentaho, mondrian, xmla

I downloaded and installed the the Mondrian 3.4.1 stable community release with the embedded derby database instance. I have many of the examples up and running on a local tomcat instance, but I cannot get the XMLA examples to work, and I am unable to communicate with the XMLA endpoint using xmla4js (http://code.google.com/p/xmla4js/ the discover-schema-rowsets example allows you to specify a url to hit, which for my local instance is localhost:8080/mondrian/xmla).

I have edited the 'datasources.xml' file as found here: http://pentahodave.mywebcommunity.org/#Apache7

The xmlaTest.jsp produces the same error as the one found at the bottom of the page, but the .class link no longer works, and I am not configured to build the source locally yet.

So my question is two-fold: Is there a way to get the xmlaTest.jsp to work without a local build and what else can I do to get xmla4js to talk to Mondrian?

Answer (score 0):

The JPivot project is very old and not up to date with the current Mondrian codeline. Actually, we will be removing JPivot from our distribution as of Mondrian 4.0. In the meanwhile, if you wish to test your XMLA service, I suggest you use [Warehouse Explorer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/whex/).